# JavaScript deletion function

Tags: javascript, html-lists, setinterval

I have such a function in JavaScript. Using it I want to delete **li** elements in **ol** with some time interval, but it actually doesn't work.

```
function Delete(){
    var node = document.getElementById("parent");
    let i = 1;
    
    while(node.firstChild){
        setInterval(function() {
        node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
        }, 200);
    }
}
```

Can you say please, what a problem???

Answer (score 0):

You making a infinite loop with the while loop. Also the [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) doing completely different what you want, but the `setInterval` and `setTimeout` will be executed in the next [event loop](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-an-event-loop-in-javascript), so the `node.firstChild` will be always the same in both case.

You wanted to do this:

```
    var node = document.getElementById("parent");
    let i = 0;
    
    for(const li of node.childNodes)
    {
        setTimeout(function() {
            node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
        }, 300 * i++); // I suppose you wanted to do this with the i 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

there is problem with set interval you have used never stated when to clear the interval and your while is just useless as after while loop termination set interval run after every 200ms  and it will go on infinitely
so I think this will work for you

```
    function Delete() {
    var node = document.getElementById("parent");
    let i = 1;
    
    if(node.firstChild){
        let interval =setInterval(function() {
          if(node.lastChild)
              node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
          else
              clearInterval(interval);
        }, 200);
    }

}
```